# Reorder a list of items and update in the database

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to reorder a list using LINQ but seem to be getting quite confused. I imagine this is something simple but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I have the following setup using blazor:

```cs
@foreach (var question in Questions)
{
    <div>
      <p @onclick="@(() => MoveQuestionUp(question))">Move up</p>
      <p @onclick="@(() => MoveQuestionDown(question))">Move down</p>
    </div>
}
```

So very basic HTML just to click to reorder and move a question up and down a list.

```cs
public void MoveQuestionUp(Question question)
{
  return MoveQuestion(question, "up");  
}

public void MoveQuestionDown(Question question)
{
  return MoveQuestion(question, "down");  
}

public async Task MoveQuestion(Question question, string direction)
{
  var currentOrder = question.Order;
  var updatedOrder = direction == "up" ? currentOrder++ : currentOrder--;

  // I'm unsure what to do at this point
  // ...

  await QuestionService.UpdateQuestionOrder(Questions);
}
```

I understand, I haven't attempted anything here because I'm utterly confused with what to do next. I understand the concept.

EDIT:

After feedback on a comment, I've update the MoveQuestion method, but I don't think it's optimal so would like to get opinions on it.

```
public async Task MoveQuestion(Question question, string direction)
{
  var questionIndex = Questions.FindIndex(q => q.Id == question.Id);
  
  if (questionIndex == 0 && direction="up")
  {
    return;
  }

  var targetQuestionIndex = direction == "up" ? questionIndex - 1 : questionIndex + 1;

  var targetQuestion = Form.Questions[targetIndex];
  (targetQuestion.Order, question.Order) = (question.Order, targetQuestion.Order);

  await QuestionService.SaveChanges();

  Questions = Questions.OrderBy(q => q.Order).ToList();

   StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: you need to swap question order with next or previous question order depends on which button clicked.

Comment: @MohammadrezaMohammadi I've updated the question based on what you have said. Is that the right kind of approach or can this be optimised?

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, however i would also check if you move the last element of the list down which also causes troubles

Comment: Also i'd keep the 2 methods to do their seperate tasks... check element is not first element on "up" and swap with previous, check element is not last on "down" and swap with next. maybe extract a method to do this swapping mechanic. ... these "up" and "down" strings you introduce results in a smell.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger Thanks for your input, are you able to provide an example? I'm not entirely sure what you mean, apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task MoveQuestionUp(Question question)
{
    var questionIndex = Questions.FindIndex(q => q.Id == question.Id);

    if(questionIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    var previousQuestion = Questions[questionIndex - 1];
    
    await SwapOrder(question, previousQuestion);

}

public async Task MoveQuestionDown(Question question)
{
    var questionIndex = Questions.FindIndex(q => q.Id == question.Id);

    if(questionIndex == Questions.Count - 1) // last question
    {
        return;
    }

    var nextQuestion = Questions[questionIndex + 1];

    await SwapOrder(question, nextQuestion)
}

private async Task SwapOrder(Question a, Question b)
{
    var temp = a.Order;
    a.Order = b.Order;
    b.Order = temp;
    
    await QuestionService.SaveChanges();

    Questions = Questions.OrderBy(q => q.Order).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have not written this with IDE so there might be syntax errors =)